# cannot use Point class from dart:math package

Tags: dart

How do I import the math Point class/package

The [documentation](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math/Point.html) indicates it is available

However I keep getting a `"Undefined class: Point"` error

My code is

```
import "dart:math";

class Pointer{

  Point point;
  Point getPoint(){
    return point;
 }
```

}

Oddly enough I can use the `dart:maths` `Random` class

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the latest SDK release?

Answer (score 1):

Update your SDK, this is a relatively new class, first committed in r28272.

Comment: Okay, I thought so....how do I update the sdk? I am using the eclipse dart editor

Comment: Sorry stupid question....just download the latest sdk ---It would be nice if the dart editor had that functionality built in

Comment: And the Dart plugin for eclipse has an update button in Preferences.